# How Swagger UI date format change?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger

Date fields of json looks like below code in Swagger UI request field, I want to change long type like "birthDate": "4312134523". how can I do it?

```
 "birthDate": "2021-06-16T20:35:53.153Z",
```

Comment: How is the `birthDate` property defined and annotated in your Java code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what type you are using for `birthDate`, but from the looks of it, I would say you are using a `java.time.Instant`. For stuff like birthdate you should use `java.time.LocalDate`. Changing the type will be better code-wise.

You can check the docs in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)

As for writing dates as timestamps, you may want to check the property `spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`. May also be relevant to look for `spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS` depending if you want to print milliseconds or nanoseconds. Both are boolean properties.